# Angular site with Web API and SharePoint Online

Tags: angularjs, azure, sharepoint

We are thinking of creating a site in Angular that would get the information from SharePoint Online site using a Web API. The site and the Web API will be  on Azure. The problem that I have is weather or not it is feaseable to query SharePoint Online using on single generic user that would authenticate for each request, or maybe using some sort of additional unique identifier for identifiyng each request, but same user overall. Do you believe it is possible? I have little experience on Azure and SharePoint Online, so any suggestion is welcomed. Thank you in advance.

BR,
Anisia

Comment: Is it a company internal application? Why not using azure AD and Single sign on for users to authenticate seamlessly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. At Web API level you can call sharepoint (use client-side object model (CSOM) for this) using single user for authentication.